# YouTube Data API Comments Issues

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am testing the youtube API with the example code they have given on their website and trying to post a comment on the videos via video ID only.

Everything works fine and when I visit the page with my account I see my comment there, except when i go to that specific video with different account than i can't find my comment or just open youtube in incognito window it doesn't show up.

On the other hand, if I manually post the comment myself it shows up everywhere, but I want to be able to do it through the API.

And I have tried it for like 40-50 Times.

My code for this:-

```
def insert_new_comment(youtube, video_id, comment,channelId):
    request = youtube.commentThreads().insert(
        part="snippet",
        body={
            "snippet": {
                "channelId": channelId,
                "videoId": video_id,
                "topLevelComment": {
                    "snippet": {
                        "textOriginal": comment
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
    response = request.execute()
```

Comment: From the YouTube API [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert), you need to set `"channelId"` in your POST request.

Comment: I have changed my code as you have mention channelId but its still not showing comments to other accounts . Why any idea please @dspencer

Comment: What `response` do you get? A `commentThread` resource or an error?

Comment: i am getting CommenThread resource in reponse.. but still not showing that comment @dspencer

Comment: And In CommentThread response .. i am always getting moderationStatus: heldForReview.. do you know why is this happening? @dspencer

Comment: Your comment needs to be reviewed by a YouTube moderator. This may be because of its content, because you're a new user or simply because they want to prevent spamming of comments via their API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After executing `response = request.execute()`, the result of the comment insertion should be inspected. A [`commentThread`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads#resource) resource for the new comment should be returned if the request was successful. This resource should look something like:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "snippet": {
    "channelId": string,
    "videoId": string,
    "topLevelComment": comments Resource,
    "canReply": boolean,
    "totalReplyCount": unsigned integer,
    "isPublic": boolean
  },
  "replies": {
    "comments": [
      comments Resource
    ]
  }
}
```

In this case, the returned `commentThread` includes a `snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.moderationStatus` element, set to `heldForReview`, which indicates that the comment has not yet been posted as it must be subject to review by a moderator.

Comment: If i am commenting on 20 videos than every response have the snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.moderationStatus heldForReview .... Why? Do you know anything about That @dspencer